# show an alternate text if there isn't search results react

Tags: reactjs, alternate, conditional-types

Hi everybody this is my code and I'm trying that the page render an alternative text if I type in the search bar and the API doesn't found the text that I'm looking for [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDjbO.png)
I tried in that way putting a alternativeText variable and then putting a conditional with the Search function but the text it's not shown.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWsOo.png)

Comment: you need paste the code here, instead of taking the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code in the image, there is a mistake in the condition checking. You are checking with the component name, which will always returns true.

Your actual condition should be,

```
  const showSearch = (searchResult?.length > 0) ? resultHtml : alternativeText;
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop it works correctly just that the text appear by default if there isn't any word in the search bar instead of be display until the API request will be made